# Passing action to one uiview to another in IOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I have created a `UIView` called `ImageShowcase` which has a `UIScrollView` and then i am adding `UIButton` inherited class call `ImageShowcaseCell`. Its working fine. One thing i am puzzled about is what is the best way to handle actions in a view controller where i have added `ImageShowCase` currently when i can handle `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` action in `UIButton` inherited class `ImageShowcaseCell` but i want to handle it in `View Controller` so that i can perform appropriate action.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your custom ImageShowcaseCell class, you can send the action up the responder chain and allow the view controller to handle it:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(someMethodOnMyViewController:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
```

Alternatively you could possibly also use:

1. delegate pattern - set your view controller as a delegate for your ImageShowcaseCell.
2. create a block based method in your custom class to execute the block after a touch.

Comment: Took the delegate option. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but why not use the responder chain and add the action on your `ImageShowCaseCell` button? If you add it like so:

```
[imageShowCaseCellInstance setTarget:nil action:@selector(methodYouWantCalledOnYourViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

As long as your `imageShowCaseCellInstance` doesn't implement this method and your view controller does, the responder chain should pass this up (because `nil` was specified for `target`) to your view controller, as long as `ImageShowCaseCell` is in your view controller's hierarchy.

Edwin's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13461504/482557) works, but by setting the target on the button you can be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it by using delegate. I already had one delegate in my `view controller` for `ImageShowCase`. So What i did i added another one in `ImageShowcase` for `ImageShowcaseCell`. Now i pass on the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event from ImageShowcaseCell to ImageShowcase, and `ImageShowcase` pass it to `view Controller`.

```
ImageShowcaseCell (TouchUpInside) ----> ImageShowcase ----> ViewController
```

Could not be cleaner. :)